# Setup two different return values for two invocations of the same method

Tags: c#, moq

suppose I have the following scenario:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int GetNextNumber();
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public int GetNextNumber()
    {
        // returns some next number. The logic of getting the next number is not importaint
    }
}
```

Now, this is the method which I want to test:

```
public void MethodToTest(IFoo foo)
    {
        int first = foo.GetNextNumber();
        int second = foo.GetNextNumber();
    }
```

How can I setup the mock, which I will pass to MethodToTest,  so that the first call of the method returns 1 and the second call to return 2, for example.
The tricky part is that the two calls of the method are indistinguishable, so I don't know how to setup them in somesort of 'order of execution'

**EDIT**: I am using Moq

Answer (score 3):

You could make a class that implements your interface and increments a value each time you call the method

```
public class TestFoo : IFoo
{
    private static int i;
    public int GetNextNumber()
    {
        return i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should initialize it:
`private static int i = 0;`

Comment: @juanmajmjr: Initialization is not required because it is a field, which is automatically initialized to 0

Comment: not in this case because he wants to return 1 and  2 but it is usually recommendable to initialize variables.

Comment: Or simply using a `pre-increment` instead of a `post-increment` has the same result.

Comment: Why is the field `i` static?

Comment: Just to make sure you always get a new number (if there are multiple instances). In the given example, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the Moq framework, you don't even have to create an custom class.

Example:

```
int i = 1;
Mock<IFoo> MockFoo = new Mock<IFoo>();
MockFoo.Setup(x => x.GetNextNumber()).Returns(i++);
```

Comment: I guess that will call an overload of `Returns` which simply takes in an `int`. So your `i` variable becomes insignificant. What about `.Returns(() => i++)` instead. That should capture the variable in a closure. The `Func<int>` delegate instance will be kept by Moq and invoked each time.